# Measuring content of a Printable before print

Tags: java, printing

I run into a problem that I cannot figure out the correct logic for it. Well, it's basically about **printing pages** in **Java**. I tried many ways but I couldn't get it worked.

My problem is that, I have lots of text to be printed (report). I want to calculate the content of each page before printing. To correctly calculate the content, I need FontMetrics but I cannot access `FontMetrics` without `Graphics` context which is passed in print(g, format, index) function in `Printable` interface.

I tried to obtain **FontMetrics** using new `Canvas().getFontMetrics(FONT).getHeight()` to measure the space taken for each line. But that didn't give accurate height. Some lines went missing.

Currently, I have a class (**MyBook**) which inherits `Book` class which implements `Pageable`. The whole content that should be written is passed to MyBook class and it separates the content for each page (Currently using `Canvas().getFontMetrics(FONT).getHeight()` but wrong).

What is the correct logic to handle **multiple pages** in **Java**? And I noticed `print(Graphics, PageFormat, pageIndex)` is called twice or three times before printing the page. Is that right?

Thanks.